# Concatenate different Json values into a single response with Scala Play

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have two different objects I want to return rendered as Json. I've written their implicit writes and I want to return them in a concatenated response.

I keep receiving the error `Compilation error[No Json serializer found for type Seq[models.RedisInfo]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type` no matter what I do

Here's how my code goes

```
def listAll() = Action.async { implicit request =>
  import models.Psql.{sqlUploadWrites => sqlWrites}
  import models.Redis.{redisWrites}

  val rFut:Future[Seq[RedisInfo]] = Redis.listAll()
  val sqlFut:Future[Seq[SQLInfo]] = SQL.listAll()
  val resp = Future.sequence(Seq(rFut, sqlFut)).map{

    /* Now I want to use their individual write methods to create the Json    
    and then wrap the result of the two into a Future[Result]

    case x: Seq[RedisInfo] => x.map(res => Json.toJson(res)(redisWrites))
    case y: Seq[SQLInfo] => y.map(res => Json.toJson(res)(sqlWrites))


  }
```

The sequences are not of equal length. This also seems to work when I do it individually.. so I'm wondering what extra complexity exists in this case.

Comment: You need to define the schema of the expected JSON

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided your write implementation of `redisWrites`, so can't comment on that.

The way I achieve something similar is first to implement Format's read and write methods and then create implicit for that.

```
Object Formatter {
    def uuidFormat: Format[UUID] = new Format[UUID] {
    def writes(uuid: UUID): JsString = JsString(uuid.toString)
    def reads(value: JsValue): JsResult[UUID] = value match {
      case JsString(x) => UUID.fromString(x) match {
        case Success(uuid) => JsSuccess(uuid)
        case Failure(msg) => JsError(__ \ 'UUID, ValidationError("invalid UUID", msg))
      }
      case _ => JsError(__ \ 'UUID, ValidationError("invalid UUID", "Missing UUID String"))
    }
  }
  implicit val uuidFormat = uuidFormat
}
```

Then import uuidFormat whereever u need to perform json serde

```
import Formatter.uuidFormat
```